# Handler to run task every 5 seconds Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, runnable

I would like to run a certain code every 5 seconds. I am having trouble achieving this with a handler. How can this be done in Kotlin? Here is what I have so far. Also to note, the variable Timer_Preview is a Handler.

[image: My Code]

Comment: you can pass a `Callable` to your `Handler`, and `sendMessageDelayed` recursively.

Comment: Please put code in the question and not link to it because a) Not everybody can get to imgur from work and b) the link might expire and this question will be useless in the future.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you can't reference a lambda you're currently in, and you can't reference the property you're defining while you're defining the lambda you're assigning to it, the best solution here is an [`object` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
val runnableCode = object: Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
    }
}
```

Assuming that this property is not a `var` because you actually want to change it while this self-calling is happening.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for! Works great

Comment: Am I right in assuming you can just create a default handler (i.e. val handler:Handler = Handler()) then start it (i.e handler.post(runnableCode)) and it'll run every 5 seconds everything you put in the run block (before handler.postDelayed...)?

Answer (score 21):

Simply Use `fixedRateTimer`

```
 fixedRateTimer("timer",false,0,5000){
        this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Change initial delay by setting another value for the third parameter.

Comment: Don't forget to clear up when leaving, though, e.g. on Android:  myFixedRateTimer.cancel()

Answer (score 5):

I recommended **SingleThread** because it is very useful. If you would like to do job for each second, you can set because parameters of it:

> Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit);

TimeUnit values are: NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS.

**Example:**

```
private fun mDoThisJob(){

    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate({
        //TODO: You can write your periodical job here..!

    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Kotlin does not yet allow recursive lambdas (see [KT-10350](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10350)), you must use other constructs, such as object expressions as in @zsmb13's answer, or ordinary functions as below

```
fun StartTimer() {
    Timer_Preview.postDelayed(Runnable { runnable() }, 5000)
}

fun runnable() {
    //Code here

    // Run code again after 5 seconds
    Timer_Preview.postDelayed(Runnable { runnable() }, 5000)
}
```

However, in your particular case, it looks like you could just call `StartTimer()` again to re-arm the timer, assuming it doesn't do anything else:

```
private val RunnableCode = Runnable {
    //Code here

    //Run code again after 5 seconds
    StartTimer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple functions:

```
private fun waitToDoSomethingRecursively() {
    handler.postDelayed(::doSomethingRecursively, 5000)
}

private fun doSomethingRecursively () {
    ...
    waitToDoSomethingRecursively()
}
```